# Will a wix bundle with 2 msi files, leave 2 uninstallers

Tags: wix, bundle

Due to another issue, i need to separate my install into 2 wix projects.
Before I go and learn how to do bundles, at the end of the bundle will I have 1 or 2 programs in my "add or remove programs" control panel screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One. By default, the bundle gets the ARP entry and the MSI packages are "hidden."

Comment: Fantastic, will investigate how to do that then.